Смещение элемента на финальном кадре
Помогите разобраться. Есть блок в котором есть изображение, svg контур, подпись и фон у подписи. Фон подписи смещен по оси Z от пользователя. При зажатии клавиши мыши, блок, как бы поворачивается к нам лицом.
Проблема в подергивании фона, а причина из-за свойства filter: opacity() и любого другого свойства filter, но так же из-за самого свойства opacity. Буду признателен за помощь, в разборе этой ситуации. Я предполагаю, что это из-за процесса отрисовки (рендера), но пока что не нашел ответа.


html {
  font-size: 10px;
}
.slider {
    position: relative;
    perspective: 100rem;
    .slider_frame {
        will-change: transform, scale, display;
        image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: all .2s ease;
        perspective: 100rem;
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        right: 0;
        top: 50%;
        aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
        width: 51rem;
        transform: rotateY(-10deg);
        transform-origin: right top;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        cursor: grab;
        filter: opacity(0);
    &:first-child {
      filter: opacity(1);
    }
        img {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50.5%;
            top: 53.5%;
            width: 90%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            display: block;
            aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
            z-index: 0;
        }
    }
}
            
.border {
    image-rendering: optimizeQuality;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    fill: none;
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    z-index: 0;
    perspective: 100rem;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    will-change: transform;
}

.bg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    fill: rgba(70, 151, 180, 0.55);
    transition: all 1s;
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) translateZ(-5rem);
    filter: blur(.15rem);
}
.slider_frame:active {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    cursor: grabbing;
}
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider_frame frame_9">
    <img src="./image/frame/9frame.webp" alt="">
    <svg class="border border_img" viewBox="0 0 830 466" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M1,40 11,30 285,30 285,11 275,1 11,1 1,11z"/>
      <text x="12" y="22" class="frame_descr">Rigging & Skinning</text>
      <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M4,65 4,45 14,35 819,35 829,45 829,65 M4,435 4,455 14,465 819,465 829,455 829,435"/>
    </svg>
    <svg class="border border_img bg" viewBox="0 0 830 466" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M1,40 11,30 285,30 285,11 275,1 11,1 1,11z"/>
    </svg>
</div>





Вы предоставили код рабочего примера? Вам стоит уточнить вашу проблему. Правильно ли я понял, что происходит ожидаемое поведение в FireFox, но не в Chrome? А почему тогда этот код работает как надо (я в Chrome запускаю, всё в порядке)?

Вообще я немного подкорректировал css, т.к. верстаю через sass и этот код у меня не работает, как здесь. Проблема в том, что когда я нажимаю на блок, он поворачивается и в конце перехода, фон подписи резко меняет позицию. В Chrome этой проблемы нет, т.к. фон просто "прилип" к подписи и при повороте блока нет эффекта 3д(надеюсь будет понятно, то, что я написал). Ни где не происходит ожидаемое :'). А здесь в примере все работает, как и планировалось. Так как я вырвал кусок кода для примера, возможно есть какое-то свойство, которое вызывает этот проблему.

"А здесь в примере все работает, как и планировалось. Так как я вырвал кусок кода для примера, возможно есть какое-то свойство, которое вызывает этот проблему." — вы начинаете запутывать ещё больше)) Сравните этот блок кода с тем, что у вас есть по факту. Может быть в том блоке у вас лишнее свойство затесалось

Я нашел из-за какого свойства происходит этот баг . . . Filter: opacity(). Так как у меня несколько подобных блоков они скрыты. Но каким образом это влияет на дочерний элемент? Ведь даже при событии нажатия нет изменения этого свойства. Я более чем уверен, что это происходит при отрисовке (рендере). Буду признателен если вы выдвините свою мысль).

Я не эксперт в HTML и CSS (уж тем более в 3d-анимациях), так что я на вряд ли помогу вам. Но вы ведь и сами видите, что мы уже выходим к правильной постановке информации. Сравните ваш изначальный текст вопроса с вашими догадками в комментариях! Я более чем уверен, что с этой дополнительной информацией вашу проблему удастся решить гораздо быстрее. Осталось отредактировать вопрос, убрав лишнее и добавив догадку с Filter: opacity() в текст вопроса

Хорошо, спасибо за помощь. Проблема не решена, но известна хоть причина. Всегда так, когда выкладываешь проблему, мгновенно приходит решение).

@2D, думаю, что всё это как-то связано с контекстом.

Дааа, похоже на это, довольно много чего сходиться. Спасибо

@2D Добавьте пожалуйста использованную картинку 9frame.webp или ссылку на неё

@Alexandr_TT Добавил.

@2D Спасибо, попробую что-нибудь сделать

@2D А с какого угла до какого нужно поворачивать?

@Alexandr_TT Изначально он стоит rotateY(-10deg), а при нажатии убирать поворот rotateY(0).

Рекомендации
Если вы создаете фигуру в SVG, старайтесь сделать это в  одном SVG.
Разнесение элементов path по нескольким svg приводит к непредсказуемым результатам при трансформации, масштабировании, анимации
Решение:
Убрал из авторского кода всё лишнее, которое либо не работает, либо работает неоднозначно.
При совместном использовании SVG и CSS анимаций, изображений и т.д для надежности и краткости решения лучше максимально переносить все элементы в SVG/
В частности фоновая картинка перенесена. Это дает гарантию, что верстка не развалится при изменении разрешения, либо при изменении экрана гаджета.


.slider {
          
        cursor: grab;
        
    }
    .frame_descr {
     
     font: bold 20px sans-serif;
     fill: black;
    }
    .path {
     fill:none;
     stroke:dodgerblue;
     stroke-width:3px;
    }
    #gr1{
    transform-origin: top right;
    transition: all .2s ease;
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        webkit-transform: rotateZ(-10deg);
        transform: rotateZ(-10deg);
        
    }

:hover#gr1 {
 webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
          transform: rotateZ(0deg);
 }
<div class="slider">
   
<svg class="border border_img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100vw" height="30vh" viewBox="70 0 830 650"  style="border:0px solid red;" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMin" >
      <g id="gr1" >
        <!-- Для анимации, чтобы не было пустых мест для курсора при наведении     -->
      <rect x="10" y="10" width="875" height="450"  rx="15" ry="15"  
          style="fill: #F9F9F9"/> 
      <text class="frame_descr" x="40" y="22" >Rigging  Skinning</text>
        <!-- Лейбл карточки -->
      <path class="path"  fill="green" stroke="blue" d="M1,40 11,30 285,30 285,11 275,1 11,1 1,11z"/>
      
        <!-- Контур карточки -->
      <path class="path" fill="none" stroke="green" d="M4,65 4,45 14,35 819,35 829,45 829,65 M4,435 4,455 14,465 819,465 829,455 829,435"/>
      
      <image xlink:href="https://i.sstatic.net/rqS8RckZ.webp" y="57" x="-250"   width="100vw" height="45vh" />
     
      </g>
      
    </svg>
    
</div>




Хахаха, спасибо конечно, но ваш результат совсем не то, что мне надо). Разделил я на разные SVG по той причине, что 3д трансформация дочерних элементов SVG очень сильно размывает их, в общем очень сильно теряется качество, а если их разделить на разные SVG, как у меня на обводку и задний фон(который смещен по оси Z), то все ок. Я был бы рад оставить все в одном SVG, но я не нашел способов обойти потерю качества. Так же вращение по оси Y, а не Z. В общем вы убрали все те эффекты, которые мне были нужны)) и конечно же проблема исчезла))), но вопрос все ещё актуален).
